# PyPDF2 PdfReadError: Could not read Boolean object

Tags: python, pypdf

I am getting the following error, when reading certain PDF files using PyPDF2. Due to the confidential nature of these documents, I can't share them, but I can try and provide information which can help solve this problem.

Stacktrace -

```
    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(pdfpath, "rb"), strict=False)
  File "/home/tata/.virtualenvs/obu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "/home/tata/.virtualenvs/obu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1732, in read
    num = readObject(stream, self)
  File "/home/tata/.virtualenvs/obu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 74, in readObject
    return BooleanObject.readFromStream(stream)
  File "/home/tata/.virtualenvs/obu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 137, in readFromStream
    raise utils.PdfReadError('Could not read Boolean object')
PdfReadError: Could not read Boolean object
```

The exception seems to be raised from the following function, in generic.py:

```
def readFromStream(stream):
    word = stream.read(4)
    if word == b_("true"):
        return BooleanObject(True)
    elif word == b_("fals"):
        stream.read(1)
        return BooleanObject(False)
    else:
        raise utils.PdfReadError('Could not read Boolean object')
```

Printing the variable **word** prints the string **trai**, but I am not sure what this string represents.

Since the [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) project seems unmaintained, can someone help me figure out a solution for this?

Note : Please note that these PDFs are not password protected.

Comment: You would need to post a bit more code and example inputs/outputs.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I am sorry, but what do you exactly mean by **bit more code**? The line `PdfFileReader(open(pdfpath, "rb"), strict=False)` indicates that I am trying to create an object of `PdfFileReader` class, but unable to do so due to the error.

Comment: close your pdf viewer ( because of permissions ) ! then use two object, first : open your pdf file, second : put that first object to PdfFileReader() ... try it

Comment: @DRPK I did close the pdf viewer, and ran this `PdfFileReader(open(pdfpath, "rb"), strict=False)` command, and it still throws the same error.

Comment: i said make a object from your open() function first! then put that object in your PdfFileReader(x,strict=False)

Comment: @DRPK Please explain how that is going be different from what I am doing. I did that as well, and nothing changed, as expected.

Comment: perhaps something went wrong on open() function, and open function return unusual output, then PdfFileReader catch that unusual output and cant read that ... !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158960/discussion-between-ganeshtata-and-drpk).

Comment: I suppose it's possible that IO latency could cause an invalid *file* object to be passed to the *PdfReader* constructor. But that seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if all  pdfs are encrypted in some way. Using the solution cited in this issue  [#53](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/53) in PyPDF2's github repository, I used the following command to generate another pdf ( The Decrypted version of the original pdf ) -

```
qpdf --password= --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf
```

and then reading output.pdf worked for me. I am not sure as to how I can determine beforehand, whether a pdf is encrypted ( or in this particular state ) or not. But this solution temporarily solves the problem.