# How to detect and eliminate this error Could not read malformed PDF

Tags: reportlab, pypdf

I have struggled with this code only to get the error given at the end.

```
from pdfrw import PdfWriter
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
import csv
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

packet = io.BytesIO(b"F4_II.txt")
c = canvas.Canvas(packet)
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
template = PdfFileReader(open('F4_II.txt'), "rb")
output = PdfFileWriter()
page = template.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))

output.addPage(page)
outputStream = open(output_path, "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

When I run this code I get this error which I can;t solve. Anybody with an idea to help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\Python\PyQt5\pdfwriter", line 10, in <module>
    new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
  File "C:\Users\Links Net\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Users\Links Net\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1697, in read
line = self.readNextEndLine(stream)
  File "C:\Users\Links Net\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1937, in readNextEndLine
    raise utils.PdfReadError("Could not read malformed PDF file")
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Could not read malformed PDF file
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for this error notification. One is that the PDF files may be encrypted. Here is a solution if that is the case: [PyPDF2 PdfReadError: Could not read Boolean object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281843/pypdf2-pdfreaderror-could-not-read-boolean-object)

New lines at the beginning of the document may be another reason. In that case, re-exporting the PDF files is recommended.

The official PyPDF documentation has more details on all the error notifications that can be raised by the PdfFileReader class [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html?highlight=pdfreaderror).

It might also help to try a different Python PDF parser / analyser like [PDFMiner](https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/index.html).